# ggplot. I have a bunch of codes that need a 0 number before the actual data in the dataframe. How I can put it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am ploting a dataframe into a shapefile map, but I need to repair a bunch of these codes.

Well. The map have 3 areas, identify by codes. 2 areas works good with the code, but all of the codes that start with 3 don´t work. These numbers need to start with 03.

So if I have 3002 in the dataframe, I need to repair to 03002. So
It´s possible to make it from R?
[image: i need to put 0 where the data start by 3]

This is a bit of my code: The column to repair with the 0 at the first 3´s its called "code2"

```
dfcsv1 <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/datastore/dump/e23bf332-be3e-4a3a-a07b-300db3d9a7be?bom=True", encoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
colnames(dfcsv1) <- c("code", "code2", "Municipio", "PCR", "TasaPCR", "PCR14", "TasaPCR14", "Muertos", "TasaMuertos")
dfcsv1$TasaMuertos = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaMuertos))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR))
dfcsv1$TasaPCR14 = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfcsv1$TasaPCR14))


dfcsv1 <- dfcsv1 %>% 
  mutate(
    municipio = stringr::str_c(code2)
  )


mapa_df <- mapa_df %>% 
  left_join(
    y  = dfcsv1 %>% select(municipio, TasaPCR14),
    by = "municipio"
  )
```

thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more concise method would be `stringr::str_pad`: (Note the default is to 'pad' to the left. see `?str_pad`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

t <- tibble(CODE = c("4444", "55555","333"))
t %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(CODE = str_pad(CODE, 5, pad = '0'))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  CODE 
  <chr>
1 04444
2 55555
3 00333
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried with: library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dfcsv1 <- read.csv("https://dadesobertes.gva.es/datastore/dump/e23bf332-be3e-4a3a-a07b-300db3d9a7be?bom=True", encoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
colnames(dfcsv1) <- c("code", "code2", "Municipio", "PCR", "TasaPCR", "PCR14", "TasaPCR14", "Muertos", "TasaMuertos")
 
dfcsv1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(dfcsv1$code2 = str_pad(dfcsv1$code2, 5, pad = '0'))

Comment: dfcsv1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(dfcsv1$code2 = str_pad(dfcsv1$code2, 5, pad = '0'))     #but don´t works..

Comment: `dfcsv1 <- dfcsv1 %>% dplyr::mutate(code2 = str_pad(code2, 5, pad = '0'))`  Try that?

Comment: Thank you very much! Now works very good!! I am very new on R :)

Comment: When you're using the pipe (`%>%`) you don't need to indicate `dfcsv1$code2` because it already knows what dataframe you're modifying.  It's the first part of that pipe stream, so you can just include the field `code2`.

Answer (score 1):

And small example:

```
library(dplyr)

t <- tibble(CODE = c("4444", "55555","3333"))
t %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(CODE = case_when(nchar(CODE) == 3 ~ paste0("00", CODE),
                                 nchar(CODE) == 4 ~ paste0("0", CODE),
                                 TRUE ~ CODE))
```